# List of all possible error types in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, runtime-error, graaljs

Is there any test suite/list of *all* possible errors defined by the ECMAScript spec? I am currently writing a JavaScript Runtime and I wanted to have fancy errors so I need to parse them from the engine and handle accordingly.

The engine is Graal.jS, if that matters.

Regards - Yush.

Comment: Does this help you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors

Comment: That is *fantastic*, thanks a lot -- are you sure those are all of them though? The list seems quite small.

Comment: I hope so :) This is what I found on a quick search on google, maybe you can search more.

Comment: Oh man, that really does include a lot of stuff but doesn't have a huge amount of possible errors. Regex and others aren't there :)

Comment: The OP actually is just in need of the [build-in error-types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#error_types).

Comment: https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/blob/master/graal-nodejs/doc/api/errors.md

Comment: @PeterSeliger From what I understand, the OP wanted only all `SyntaxError`s, not all errors type..

Comment: @PeterSeliger You're right. But still, I think what you sent is not so helpful to OP, because he specifically asked for syntax errors (and I think that what I sent is a good start). Anyway, I think @ Bergi has really nice answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any list of all possible errors defined by the ECMAScript spec?

Sure, the list of possible error types is in the ECMAScript spec itself. But it seems you're only interested in `SyntaxError` specifically.

> Is there any list of all possible *syntax* errors in JavaScript?

No. The ECMAScript specification does not mandate any specific error messages for syntax errors. Any engine is allowed to bring their own, and is also allowed to implement syntax extensions.

> The engine is Graal.jS, if that matters.

Yes, it does matter. Graal.js *does* implement some [syntax extensions](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/js/JavaScriptCompatibility/#language-features). As for the list of possible parser error messages, you probably best look into the [source code of the parser](https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/blob/master/graal-js/src/com.oracle.js.parser/src/com/oracle/js/parser/Parser.java) itself.

Here's a list of errors that I extracted (dirtily with the regex `/(?<=throw error\().*?(?=,[^,]*\);)/g`) from the mentioned file:

```
ECMAErrors.getMessage("syntax.error.redeclare.variable", varNode.getName().getName())
AbstractParser.message("arguments.in.field.initializer")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_LVALUE)
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_LVALUE)
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_LVALUE)
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_LVALUE)
String.format("unexpected node in AssignmentPattern: %s"
String.format("nullish coalescing operator cannot immediately contain, or be contained within
AbstractParser.message("use.strict.non.simple.param")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_EXPECTED_STMT, "function declaration")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_EXPECTED_STMT, "let declaration")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_EXPECTED_STMT, "const declaration")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_EXPECTED_STMT, "class declaration")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_EXPECTED_STMT, "async function declaration")
AbstractParser.message("invalid.private.ident")
AbstractParser.message("multiple.constructors")
AbstractParser.message("invalid.private.ident")
AbstractParser.message("unexpected.token"
AbstractParser.message("invalid.private.ident")
ECMAErrors.getMessage("syntax.error.redeclare.variable", classElement.getPrivateName())
AbstractParser.message("invalid.private.ident")
AbstractParser.message("generator.constructor")
AbstractParser.message("accessor.constructor")
AbstractParser.message("async.constructor")
AbstractParser.message("static.prototype.method")
AbstractParser.message("private.constructor.method")
AbstractParser.message("constructor.field")
AbstractParser.message("static.prototype.field")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_ESCAPED_KEYWORD, ident.getName())
expectMessage(IDENT, ident.getToken())
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_ESCAPED_KEYWORD, ident.getName())
expectMessage(IDENT, ident.getToken())
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_ESCAPED_KEYWORD, ident.getName())
AbstractParser.message("strict.name", ident.getName(), contextString)
AbstractParser.message("missing.destructuring.assignment")
AbstractParser.message("missing.const.assignment"
ECMAErrors.getMessage("syntax.error.redeclare.variable", name)
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_LVALUE)
"Rest element must be last"
"Unexpected element after rest element"
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_LVALUE)
"Unexpected element after rest element"
"Expected a valid binding identifier"
"Expected a valid binding identifier"
String.format("unexpected node in BindingPattern: %s"
AbstractParser.message("invalid.for.await.of")
AbstractParser.message("missing.const.assignment"
AbstractParser.message("missing.destructuring.assignment")
AbstractParser.message("for.each.without.in")
AbstractParser.message("many.vars.in.for.in.loop", isForOf || isForAwaitOf ? "of" : "in")
AbstractParser.message("for.in.loop.initializer", isForOf || isForAwaitOf ? "of" : "in")
AbstractParser.message("not.lvalue.for.in.loop", isForOf || isForAwaitOf ? "of" : "in")
AbstractParser.message("undefined.label", ident.getName())
AbstractParser.message("illegal.continue.stmt")
AbstractParser.message("undefined.label", ident.getName())
AbstractParser.message("illegal.break.stmt")
AbstractParser.message("unexpected.token"
AbstractParser.message("strict.no.with")
AbstractParser.message("duplicate.label", ident.getName())
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_EXPECTED_OPERAND
AbstractParser.message("missing.catch.or.finally")
AbstractParser.message("strict.no.nonoctaldecimal")
AbstractParser.message("strict.no.octal")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_EXPECTED_OPERAND
AbstractParser.message("expected.comma"
AbstractParser.message("expected.property.id"
AbstractParser.message("expected.comma"
AbstractParser.message("multiple.proto.key")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_PROPERTY_REDEFINITON, property.getKeyName())
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_PROPERTY_REDEFINITON, property.getKeyName())
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_PROPERTY_REDEFINITON, property.getKeyName())
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_PROPERTY_REDEFINITON, property.getKeyName())
AbstractParser.message("strict.no.nonoctaldecimal")
AbstractParser.message("strict.no.octal")
AbstractParser.message("expected.target")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_EXPECTED_OPERAND, IMPORT.getName())
AbstractParser.message("unexpected.token"
AbstractParser.message("invalid.super")
AbstractParser.message("unexpected.import.meta")
AbstractParser.message("unexpected.ident", meta)
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_EXPECTED_OPERAND, IMPORT.getName())
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_EXPECTED_STMT, "generator function declaration")
JSErrorType.SyntaxError, AbstractParser.message("strict.no.func.decl.here")
JSErrorType.SyntaxError, AbstractParser.message("no.func.decl.here")
AbstractParser.message("strict.param.redefinition", duplicateParameter.getName())
AbstractParser.message("unexpected.token"
AbstractParser.message("unexpected.token"
AbstractParser.message("strict.cant.delete.ident", ident.getName())
AbstractParser.message("strict.cant.delete.private")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_ARROW_PARAMETER)
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_ARROW_PARAMETER)
AbstractParser.message("expected.arrow.parameter")
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_ARROW_PARAMETER)
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_ARROW_PARAMETER)
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_ARROW_PARAMETER)
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_ARROW_PARAMETER)
AbstractParser.message(MESSAGE_INVALID_ARROW_PARAMETER)
AbstractParser.message("unterminated.template.expression")
ECMAErrors.getMessage("syntax.error.redeclare.variable", ident.getName())
AbstractParser.message("duplicate.import.assertion", assertionKey)
AbstractParser.message("expected.binding.identifier")
AbstractParser.message("invalid.export")
expectMessage(IDENT, reservedWordToken)
AbstractParser.message("new.target.in.function")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'm not a JS dev so wasn't aware that there were multiple error types. Although thanks for the sources! Cheers \o